# Running PowerShell script as admin and with PowerShell window hidden

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that needs to run as administrator when i click the .bat file to launch it, however, i also need the PowerShell window hidden. I have a script that currently launches it as admin, but i need it to hide the window as well. I have tried to put in -windowstyle hidden, but it does not work. Here is my launch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%PMCS_Full_InProgress.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Can anyone help me hide the window? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `PowerShell -WindowStyle hidden` will hide the window. Using `-NoProfile` and `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` should already do the run as admin part. So your Endcode will be: `PowerShell -WindowStyle hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\PMCS_Full_InProgress.ps1`. don't need any more than that

Comment: It doesn't look like it ran as admin unfortunately, is there another way to arrange it or word it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was not putting `-windowstyle hidden`insideof`the "& {Start-Process PowerShell -Arguments . . .}` so it wasn't recognizing it at all.  I was trying to put it on the outside. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I assume you're just right clicking the .bat file and saying "Run as admin" right? Otherwise their are ways to run the script with elevated rights  when called. For highest elevation, I would run as system using PsExec from Sysinternals. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx

Comment: you don't need to start powershell with `start-process` in a batch file. just call the script with the code I wrote in the comments of your question. This is just not as nice and correct as it could be right now